# Given $|\vec x|=2, |\vec y|=3$ and the angle between them is 120°, determine the unit vector in the opposite direction of $|\vec x - \vec y|$.

Tags: vectors

"Given $|\vec x|=2, |\vec y|=3$ and the angle between them is 120°, determine the unit vector in the opposite direction of $|\vec x - \vec y|$."

To solve this problem, would I need to use sine law or cosine law, or would I need to rewrite the vectors as Cartesian vectors, so that they are easier to calculate? I thought the answer was $-\frac 1 2 \vec x + \frac 1 3 \vec y$ at first, but that doesn't seem right, given the angle. Could you please show me how to find the solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: $|\vec x - \vec y|~$ doesn't have a direction, so what does opposite direction mean?

Comment: I assume the writer of the question might have meant $\vec x - \vec y$, not the magnitude of the two vectors subtracted.

Comment: Since $\lvert \vec x - \vec y\rvert$ is an essential thing to compute as part of the solution, and we already have magnitudes twice in the problem statement, perhaps the writer got momentarily confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Denote the origin by $O = (0,0)$ and consider the vectors $x = (2,0)$ and $y = (3\cos(\theta),3\sin(\theta))$.

Based on such considerations, we are able to find the vector $v$ in the exercise as follows:

\begin{align*}
v = -\frac{x - y}{\|x - y\|} = -\frac{(2 - 3\cos(\theta),-3\sin(\theta))}{\sqrt{13 - 12\cos(\theta)}}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand now, thanks!

Comment: @FelixAn You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is to find a unit vector in the direction opposite
$\vec x - \vec y$
then the main thing you need to do is find the length of $\vec x - \vec y$
so that you can scale $\vec x - \vec y$ to a unit vector.
Then reverse its direction.

You can use the law of cosines to find the length of $\vec x - \vec y$,
assign a convenient orthonormal basis in which to evaluate the length of that vector, or whatever method finds the length.

One thing for sure is that the answer will multiply $\vec x$ and $-\vec y$ by the same factor, so we know immediately that $-\frac 1 2 \vec x + \frac 1 3 \vec y$ cannot possibly be the answer.